How to get docstrings of fields of a NamedTuple or dataclass?
I'm using a NamedTuple with comments as suggested for Python 3.6+:
from typing import NamedTuple

class Config(NamedTuple):
  buy_fee: float
  """My field description..."""
  # ...

Now I'd like to programmatically get the docstrings of the fields to generate a nice help message.
I tried to use inspect as follows:
[(f, inspect.getdoc(getattr(cls, f))) for f in cls._fields]

But I only get some default comment values: [('buy_fee', 'Alias for field number 0'), ...].
I tried to convert the class to a @dataclass and extract the docs with
[(f.name, inspect.getdoc(f)) for f in dataclasses.fields(cls)]

But this approach also failed, I got just [('buy_fee', None), ...].
Is there some way to achieve this?

Presumably you looked at this answer, which does also show assigning directly to __doc__ "if you care about full compatibility with Python's help function".

@jonrsharpe Thanks! When reading that answer I didn't realize compatibility with the help function is the same for inspect.getdoc.

I think the way you add a docstring to a variable/field has to be different.
You can't just put it on the bottom of the field.
You can use field(metadata={"doc": "My field description..."}) instead.
I tried it here and it worked:
My Working Solution
Here the Code:
from dataclasses import dataclass, field, fields
import inspect

@dataclass
class Config:
    buy_fee: float = field(metadata={"doc": "My field description..."})
    # ...

# Access the docstring
field_objects = fields(Config)
for field in field_objects:
    print(f"{field.name}: {field.metadata.get('doc', '')}")

Your Code still will work fine, as before:
working show
Does that solve your problem?

Indeed that works nicely, thanks! Still I wonder if there is a solution that'd work with built-in Python's mechanisms for docstrings introspection.
